# Two-legged Oauth in Android

Tags: android, oauth

What external libraries, if any, do I need to use in order to connect to a web service that uses two-legged Oauth?

Also, if anyone has any sample code of how to authenticate, I'd greatly appreciate it. All the examples I've seen (mainly Twitter) are using three-legged Oauth with tokens, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use example from this page: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples

Answer (score 0):

Google has just released an API for OAuth 2.0 Authentication, among other things, called Google Play Services.

https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services